# Render Queue Sorting - Best method for generating sorting IDs

Tags: rendering, pipeline, sorting

I'm trying to implement a method for sorting my renderable items before drawing them into screen. To do so, I have been tinkering with the idea of using an 64 bit key to store the state of each rendering item. Exactly as described here: http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=86

As an example, let's say I want to use a 16 bit sorting key to sort per shader and mesh. Therefore, highest 8 bits will be to store the ShaderID and the last 8 for the MeshID.

I understand the concept and the necessary bit operations used to combine ShaderID and MeshID into the 16 bits key. My main issue is that I'm not exactly sure which method to use for generating the 8 bits ID for each part of the key (ShaderID and MeshID)

Searching the internet and thinking about it I have seen three possible methods, each with their pros and cons:

**Hashing Method**

Use a good hashing algorithm and generate a hash value for the Shader and another for the Mesh (with a value unique per object so we don't use the same value to feed the hash). Then, use bit operators to convert the value returned by the hash from 32bits (or whatever output the hash function returns) into the required 8 bits and, finally, combine them.

This is the method I have seen recommended by most pros and it seems good but, **my main issue is, that it doesn't seem to protect against collisions**. As far as I see it, **I could be unlucky, compute the hash for my shader, turn it into a 8 bit value, and end up having the same key as another shader**, as there are only 256 possible options. Even if the hash is good the issue could still happen **even when I have still not run out of IDs**.

**Render Sort ID Manager**

Instead of using a hashing algorithm. I could use a manager that keeps a list of free IDs and returns a free one for each Shader or Mesh that requires one.

This gives **great control over each part of the key**. The generator provides keys that go from 0 - 255. Therefore **I'm sure there will never be any collisions and no two shaders will use the same ID** if they are different. If I'm ever out of IDs I can simply pop out a message to notify performance could be degraded due to bad sorting and move on.

**Main issue I see with this method is that it's a bit memory hungry**. I would have to keep different lists of free IDs for each part of the key. In a real example I could have a list of 2^16 integer for example just for possible texture combinations. And there would be other lists for other parts of the key.

Does anybody have any opinion on this topic? I have not been able to find any conclusive information about it.

**Counter Method**

Simply use a counter that increases by one for each type of resource, so a counter for Shaders and another for Meshes. Use the value returned by the counter as ID for the resource.

This method seems incomplete as **it doesn't take into account what happens when I go above the number of bits assigned for the resource**. I could apply a modulo operator so once I reach maximum value supported by the render key, counter returns to the start, but this wouldn't consider that **I could end up reusing IDs that are still being used**.

The good thing about this method is that **it's simple and requires very low memory**.

Is there anything I am missing? Do you guys use any of these method or another one? I'm a little hesitant right now.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use each of the above methods on a sample scene and see which one works best for your project?

Comment: Hello! Yes, currently I have implemented the second method the "Render Sort ID Manager" as I found it to be the most "correct", but I'm interested in seeing how others might have dealt with this issue. Thanks for answering!